# Given an invertible matrix $A$ and a constant $c$, can we show $~(cI+AA^\text T)x=b~$ is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Given an invertible matrix $A$ and for $~c>0~$, show that there exists a solution to $~(cI+AA^\text T)x=b~$.

I know $A$ is invertible. Is this enough to guarentee a solution? If not, what assumptions would we need on A or b to make this true?

Comment: Take $A=I$ and $c=-1$. Then $cI+AA^T=0$ is not invertible. You want to solve $Bx=b$, with $B=cI+AA^T$. For a unique solution you just need that $\det(B)\neq 0$.

Comment: Unless it is known that $c>0$, we would need to know more about $A$ to guarantee that a solution exists.

Comment: If we assume c>0, then what would we need to know about A?

Comment: hint: eigenvalue decomposition

Comment: If $c > 0$, it is invertible even if $A$ is not!

Comment: Damien’s right, because the matrix would be positive definite.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: The easiest way seems to calculate $v^T B v$, for any vector $v$